# Some of my PHP string disappears when being passed into SQL

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, phpbb3

I've created a Wordpress plugin that detects when a post is published and creates a topic in a phpBB installation.

As part of the plugin, the Wordpress post's excerpt is passed to the phpBB SQL database as the post text, followed by a few line breaks and a 'read more' link that is a permalink to the Wordpress post.

The excerpt + link is created as follows:

```
$wparticle_excerpt = get_the_excerpt()."<br /><br /><a href=\"".get_permalink()."\" title=\"".get_the_title()."\" class=\"postlink\">Click here to read the full article &rarr;</a>";
```

Then it's escaped:

```
$wparticle_excerpt = $con->real_escape_string( $wparticle_excerpt );
```

And is then written into the SQL database using the following query:

```
$sql_write_post = "INSERT INTO phpbb_posts (

    topic_id,
    forum_id,
    poster_id,
    icon_id,
    post_time,
    post_approved,
    post_reported,
    enable_bbcode,
    enable_smilies,
    enable_magic_url,
    enable_sig,
    post_subject,
    post_text,
    post_checksum,
    post_attachment,
    post_postcount,
    post_edit_time,
    post_edit_user,
    post_edit_count,
    post_edit_locked

    ) VALUES (

    /* topic_id */          $new_topic_id,
    /* forum_id */          $forum_to_post_in,
    /* poster_id */         $userid_to_assign,
    /* icon_id */           0,
    /* post_time */         $date_to_assign,
    /* post_approved */     1,
    /* post_reported */     0,
    /* enable_bbcode */     0,
    /* enable_smilies */    0,
    /* enable_magic_url */  1,
    /* enable_sig */        0,
    /* post_subject */      '$wparticle_title',
    /* post_text */         '$wparticle_excerpt',
    /* post_checksum */     '$wparticle_excerpt_md5',
    /* post_attachment */   0,
    /* post_postcount */    1,
    /* post_edit_time */    0,
    /* post_edit_user */    0,
    /* post_edit_count */   0,
    /* post_edit_locked */  0

    )";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql_write_post)) { die ("Error while creating post: " . mysqli_error($con)); }
```

The problem is that when I check the output, all I get are the two line breaks and the read more link. The actual excerpt, the part created by get_the_excerpt(), is completely gone. All I get is this:

```
<br />
<br />
<a href="http://localhost/wptest/?p=167" title="Test Post" class="postlink">Click here to read the full article &rarr;</a>
```

I've dumped the $wparticle_excerpt variable after escaping it, and I know it's good. It's just one long string.

If I put any text in front of the excerpt, that stays, as long as it's hard-coded in PHP. Then there's a blank space where the excerpt should be, then the line breaks. No matter what I do I can't keep the excerpt there, it just disappears somewhere.

I'm sure this is the most simple thing but I'm mostly self-taught and I have no idea how or why this is happening. Any help would be incredibly appreciated. Please let me know if I haven't explained something properly.

The phpbb_posts table I'm writing to is utf8_bin and the post_text field in there is mediumtext type and utf8_bin, if this is of any help.

Comment: What is the length of the field you're inserting the information into?

Comment: @BenM If I understand your question correctly (forgive me, I'm fumbling in the dark here) the field is set to mediumtext, which should give it a theoretical size limit of 16,777,215 chars. The total size of the string I'm passing is only around 450 chars.

Comment: Whats the return from get_the_excerpt()?

Comment: @Manu The get_the_excerpt() function returns just a plain string, and as far as I can tell it returns the string correctly. If I dump the $wparticle_excerpt variable just before inserting it into SQL, I get a the full proper string: the excerpt of the article, two line breaks, and a link.

Comment: Can you post a example of the escaped string?

Comment: @Manu Sure thing. var dump prints this:

`string(492) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dictum aliquam vestibulum. Integer semper aliquet nunc. Aliquam tortor sapien, feugiat id facilisis eu, sodales suscipit tellus. Aenean vitae nisl lacus. Integer a imperdiet dui. Maecenas...<br /><br /><a href=\"http://localhost/wptest/?p=152\" title=\"Curabitur ut elementum ante, et venenatis turpis. Quisque congue egestas libero vitae viverra.\" class=\"postlink\">Click here to read the full article &rarr;</a>"`

Comment: Try replace the "Integer" words. Thats the only thing I see. Maybe you can post you SQL Query too?

Comment: @Manu Unfortunately I'm having the same problem with any excerpt, that's just one I happened to populate with Lorem Ipsum. I'll edit the question above to add the SQL query as well.

Comment: Thats really tricky. I don't see anything wrong. For testing save the string directly to your database without escaping it.

Comment: @Manu No difference I'm afraid. Appreciate your thoughts, though!